# Display text and image using jquery qtip

Tags: jquery, qtip

I am using the jquery qTip plugin to display tooltips, and it works fine if the tooltip has only text to display. However, I want text and an image in the tooltip. The text and the image should be displayed side by side.

```
   <img src="../images/sicon.png" alt="beside this tooltip there is a image &lt;img src=&quot;../images/bird.png&quot;/&gt;" class="ToolTip">



    var style = { width: '225px' };
        $(".ToolTip").each(function (index, element)
        {
            var title = $(element).attr('alt');
            $.qtip.bindQtip(element, title, {}, {}, {}, style , {});
        });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @TusharGupta:its a plug in..i am just wondering if there is any function which i could make use of to send img and text as source..for now i am using bindqtip function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i solved this.. instead of sending text i sent "div"  with text and image tag in it as content